# Clojure - Quoting a List Adds "quote" text to list - How Do I Remove This?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I have the scenario where I have a map that has a field that is going to be a series of nested lists to create a tree like structure. I've quoted the lists with ' so that it works, without that I get errors as it tries to execute it.

```
(def test-map
  {:tree '("1" "2" "3" '("1" "2"))})
```

The problem is this seems to add the word "quote" to the actual list.

```
(:tree test-map)
;("1" "2" "3" (quote ("1" "2")))

(first (last (:tree test-map)))
;quote
```

My question is how can I get rid of this "quote" text. My goal is to be able to work through these types of list by a certain number and be able to output the strings in sequence at a given depth.

```
(for [text (second (last (:tree test-map)))]
  text)
```

This is a basic idea, but it feels weird having to use second here when visually looking at it the list I'm working through is the first item.

Is there a way to do what I want with lists? Is it a better idea to use vectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't quote the inner list. Quotation applies to an entire nested structure, so if you wish to build a particular data structure you can just put a quote at the front and then write out the data structure normally.